# Django - How to specify 'NOT IN' in 'limit_choices_to'?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How to specify 'NOT IN'  in 'limit_choices_to'? I just want to fetch all the customer details except if they are in one particular status.

```
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, limit_choices_to={'status__in': ['active']})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just used the Q object instead of a dictionary.

```
limit_choices_to = ~models.Q(status__in = ['xxxxxx']))
```